# How to Sort a Pivot Table Generated by Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, pivot

I have been trying to sort a pivot table generated by pandas. This where I am at so far:

```
pv=pd.pivot_table(data,index=["TIN"], columns=["Tax Type"], values=["FileFreq"], aggfunc=[np.sum], margins=True)
```

A subset of the data I am working on is as follows:

| TIN | Tax Type | FileFreq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 875-729 | CWT | 1 |
| 875-729 | CWT | 1 |
| 875-729 | CWT | 1 |
| 875-729 | CWT | 1 |
| 875-729 | EWT | 1 |
| 875-729 | EWT | 1 |
| 875-729 | EWT | 1 |
| 875-729 | EWT | 1 |
| 875-729 | EWT | 1 |
| 138-075 | CWT | 1 |
| 138-075 | CWT | 1 |
| 138-075 | CWT | 1 |
| 138-075 | CWT | 1 |
| 138-075 | EWT | 1 |
| 138-075 | EWT | 1 |
| 138-075 | EWT | 1 |
| 138-075 | EWT | 1 |
| 138-075 | EWT | 1 |
| 138-075 | EWT | 1 |
| 138-075 | EWT | 1 |
| 944-507 | CWT | 1 |
| 944-507 | CWT | 1 |
| 944-507 | EWT | 1 |
| 944-507 | EWT | 1 |
| 944-507 | EWT | 1 |
| 944-507 | EWT | 1 |

A snapshot  of the  resulting pivot table I got from the whole dataset is given below:

```
                             Tax Type Sum of File Freq
```

| TIN | CWT | EWT | All |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 130-344 | 11 | 7 | 18 |
| 138-075 | 12 | 9 | 21 |
| 151-387 | 12 | 12 | 24 |
| 230-328 | 12 | 12 | 24 |
| 257-018 | 12 | 12 | 24 |
| 484-606 | 9 | 9 | 18 |
| 597-665 | 10 | 10 | 20 |
| 875-729 | 10 | 12 | 22 |
| 894-747 | 12 | 12 | 24 |
| 944-507 | 6 | 11 | 17 |
| All | 106 | 106 | 212 |

I would like to sort from lowest to highest first by the CWT column (one table), then by the EWT column (another table). Have been trying different recommendations from similar questions posted here in SO but to no avail.
One of those I tried is

```py
pvsort = pv.reindex(pv['FileFreq'].sort_values(by=['CWT']).index)
```

but I am getting an error
Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: did you use sort_values? `pv.sort_values(by='CWT')` ? if yes what exactly is the problem, please elaborate. also if possible , provide us with a reproducible dataset

Comment: thanks anky. sorry it is my first time to ask a question here. how do i send a data set?

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) are a good reads :-)

Comment: Remember that levels in pivot table are stored in MultiIndex objects. You can sort data by column names but you need to be more specific in defining them. You can use print(pv.columns) to see what I mean. If you provide a dataset, we will be able to give you more detailed answer.

Comment: You can't format code (properly that is) in comments. You should edit your question instead.

Comment: thanks, edited my question already to provide a subset of the data